# Cloudfront adding extra latency for API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

When calling the regional API Gateway Endpoints, response time is ~300ms, (same with custom domain name).

- ~300ms for https://xxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stage/api/users
- ~300ms with custom domain name https://api.myexample.com/api/users

Our webapp gets served from Cloudfront + S3 at https://myexample.com

Now to avoid CORS, I added another origin (API Gateway) in Cloudfront with behavior of `/api/*` to point to API Gateway

- ~800ms for https://myexample.com/api/users -> https://xxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stage/api/users

Basically Cloudfront is adding those extra 500ms, is there a way to optimize this?

I found similar question, but that was unanswered: [API Gateway edge-optimized added latency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52999581/api-gateway-edge-optimized-added-latency)

Answer (score 0):

Every request to this API path will be routed to your origin. I mean the client will connect to the closest POP then CloudFront will connect to the API Gateway to forward the request.

We faced the same kind of results with a custom origin.

You should review your connection settings. Establishing an HTTPs connection is a lengthy operation, check the `connection timeout` setting for your origin. You need of course to warmup the POP before your tests.

You can collect [server-timing headers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/understanding-response-headers-policies.html#server-timing-header). That's a great way to check if you are reusing a connection or not and where you waste time.

I'm not 100% sure why, but we also noticed that activating the `origin shield` option for custom origins reduces the latency.