# CNAME record from my domain to API Gateway invoke URL not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, api-gateway

Is it possible to CNAME my own domain to AWS API gateway invoke URL?

For example, i owned example.com. I want to create (in Route53) a CNAME record from api.example.com to abcefg.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com.

Using my terminal, i am able to resolve api.example.com to the invoke URL listing all 4 AWS DNS server. However, i am unable to reach my API via api.example.com but i can do so with the invoke URL without any issue.

May i know if such a CNAME can work at all or must i use a custom domain to achieve that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the [API Gateway console](https://ap-southeast-1.console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/home?region=ap-southeast-1#/custom-domain-names), you have to declare the custom domain that you want to use to access your API.

You will need to provide:

- the protocol (HTTP or WebSocket)
- the domain's name
- the TLS version (leave default if not sure)
- the endpoint configuration (if not sure, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49845124/598812))
- an ACM certificate (if you don't have one, you will need to create one in [ACM](https://ap-southeast-1.console.aws.amazon.com/acm/home?region=ap-southeast-1#/))

The process is pretty straightforward but you will find more documentation on this process in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html?icmpid=docs_apigateway_console) if needed.