# how can I use custom domain on API gateway with S3 static website hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I setup my domain on API gateway to use API calls with domain.

When I call base url with domain I got S3 error instead lambda result.

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>v1/mystage</Key>
<RequestId>ED11385C2BCE1D98</RequestId>
<HostId>
6QOcio6aofUYI2sTDsxJxE6BR06UfxKvNRT+L12QxGhvJvsmuJB4BYwgexYtPK++4K919Nh9bTM=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

can anyone clarify whether if its possible to use my domain in API gateway but its already used for **S3 static website hosting**?

Comment: [How to serve an AWS EC2 instance from S3 Subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60474201/1695906) isn't an exact duplicate, but provides some additional details of serving S3 plus something else (EC2 instead of API Gateway, but the concepts are similar) from the same domain, via CloudFront.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use same domain for multiple resources you need to setup CloudFront distribution and configure different origins and behaviors for them, based on URI

Comment: In this configuration, API Gateway should be deployed as regional rather than edge-optimized, for best performance and most sensible handling of request headers.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49845124/1695906

Comment: Yes, but edge-optimized is also setting up cloudFront in front of API GW) You just don't see that implementation in Console

Comment: Correct, which is why you don't use an edge-optimized deployment when you're providing your own CloudFront distribution.  If you do, everything loops through CloudFront twice.

Comment: And I didn't suggest that)

Comment: No, you didn't... but you also didn't mention that it should be avoided, which is the point of my original comment.

Comment: Oh, your intention was to extend my answer, not to confront. My bad, thanks)